# How to protect a folder in windows 10 from being deleted BUT keep the permission to modify (add or delete ) files inside that folder?

Tags: directory, windows-10, subdirectory, delete-file

I have one folder with hundreds of photos subfolders inside it. Each subfolder is a folder with each client's photos, and each folder is named with the person's name.

I constantly add more photos to some client's folder. A few times I delete a photo inside that folder, or edit a photo.

But sometimes by accident I have already deleted the entire folder of the person, losing all the photos for that particular person. And also, from bad luck, I emptied the trash bin and lost that entire especific folder for good. Of course, I only noticed that that person's folder disappeared a lot of days after.

Sometimes I never knew when that person's folder was (accidentally) deleted. It's rare to happen, but It has already happened.

The workaround I've used (to success sometimes) is  to use some "undelete" software to search for those deleted for good pictures inside the hard disk. Sometimes it works, sometimes not, but it's time consuming to find, in thousands of deleted pictures on purpose, the accidentally deleted ones...

So... is there a way to protect a Windows 10 folder from being accidentally deleted,  but still allowing me to change the contents inside it? Add more files to it, delete or edit some files inside it? And also to be able to create more folders in it's parent folder?

I need just to be blocked from accidentally deleting the folder. Of course, if needed I could "unblock" that folder to erase on purpose.

Or some kind of intelligent backup that if the "newer"backup has less folders than the "older" backup, it would ask if it's correct to erase that (accidentally erased) folder.

Thanks!